# Virtualbox 3 kills my wireless when I start a VM

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I've upgraded from an older version of VirtualBox, but when I try to run any of my VMs (Win7, XP Pro), the internet connection stops working.

My OS is Vista 32Bit and I have a D-link router. When the VM starts the wireless connection is seen by Vista as "Local connection only". This worked with the older VBox.

I've even tried to uninstall and reinstall, but no luck. The connection is restored only if I reboot, but drops again when I start a VM...

Comment: File a bug report with the VirtualBox team.  They're real good about getting fixes done for stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

it is my understanding that using a virtual machine with a wireless adapter is a hit or miss kinda deal. it may work, but no promises. I believe you really need a wired connection